# How to create functional search box to query data from a certain table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I would like to create functional **search box** to query data from a certain table.

**Database Details:**

- table name : inventories
- primary key : id
- unique index : sku
- size = 120, 000 rows

---

**Search box Details :**

Blade/HTML

```
            {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'UrlController@query', 'method' => 'get')) }}

                <input autofocus name="search" id="search" placeholder="Enter Catalog # " type="text" />

                <span class="pull-right">

                    {{ Form::submit('Search', array('class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm')) }}

                </span>

            {{ Form::close() }}
```

[image]

As you can see, my search box name is `search`

---

**Controller Function :**

```
public function query() {

        // grab GET parameters
        $search = Input::get('search');

        // apply search filter
        if ($search){

            //$inventories = Inventory::all(); # It's works if I do this

            $inventories = Inventory::where(function($inventories) use ($search){
                $inventories->where('search', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
            });


            return View::make('inventories.index')
            ->with('inventories', $inventories);
        }else

        return View::make('inventories.index');

    }
```

---

**At the end :**

I couldn't get any result(s) to display.

Did I do something wrong ? here :

```
$inventories = Inventory::where(function($inventories) use ($search){
                $inventories->where('search', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
            });
```

What is the most efficient way to accomplish this kind of task in Laravel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not use **get()** method

```
$inventories = Inventory::where(function($inventories) use ($search){
                $inventories->where('search', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
            })->get();
```

And Also use **paginate()** method

```
$inventories = Inventory::where(function($inventories) use ($search){
                    $inventories->where('search', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
                })->paginate(15);
```

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Hey, I tried `get()` and it takes forever. When I tried `$inventories = $inventories->paginate(10);` , It's very fast.

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it works well for me >>

$columns = Schema::getColumnListing('inventories');

```
    $query = User::query();

    $search = Input::get('search');
    foreach($columns as $column){
        $query->orWhere($column, 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
    }
    $inventories = $query->get();

    return $inventories;
```